# Get Firebase Users from Auth using array of uid

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get a list of users but I need to pass a list of UIDs and I have been checking the firebase `admin.auth` documentation and I found the following method:

`getUsers(identifiers: UserIdentifier[]): Promise<GetUsersResult>`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getusers

But when I tried to call the method and pass an array of User UIDs, it says `admin.auth(...).getUsers is not a function`

Here is what I am trying:

On client Side:

```
const query = firebase.firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .where('userType', '==', '1');
  .limit(5);

const results = []
query.get().then((collection) => {
  collection.forEach((snapshot) => {
    if (!snapshot.empty) {
      results.push(snapshot);
      }
    });

const userIdList = results.map(doc => doc.id);

axios.post('myAdmin/getUsers', { userIdList })
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

On server Side:

```
const serviceAccount = require('./myServiceAccount');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://mydatabase-url.firebaseio.com',
});


m.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { userIdList } = req.body
    const users = await admin.auth().getUsers(userIdList);
    res.json({
      users,
    });

  };
```

Do you know if that method is still valid ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it, after updating `firebase-admin` to the latest version.

Also I did a change to send the user ids as object array:

```
const userIdList = results.map(doc => {return { uid: doc.id } });

axios.post('myAdmin/getUsers', { userIdList })
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```